# Xamarin.UITest: How to set date in datepicker on iOS?

Tags: ios, datepicker, automation, ios-ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

I need to set date in datepicker on iOS 10.3 using Xamarin.UITest 2.0.9.
Repl crashes on attempt to get the tree but I use the following query `q => q.Class("UIDatePicker")` for this element.

I'm trying to set date by invoke SetDate method https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIDatePicker.SetDate/p/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDate/System.Boolean/
using the following code
`app.Query(q => q.Class("UIDatePicker").Invoke("setDate", date, false))` where date is a DateTime object, but it throws the exception:

```
System.Exception : Error while performing Query([unknown])
----> System.Exception : Invoking an iOS selector requires either 0 or an uneven number of arguments (they have to match up pairwise including method name).
```

Also I tried to set date in the following way:

`app.Query(q => q.Class("UIDatePicker").Invoke("setDate", date))`
but it returns `object[1] { null }` and nothing happens.

DatePicker image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVXxZ.png)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make it work, but there are few details I had to add.
For me the actions that worked for setting time on time picker were:

```
app.Query(c => c.Class("UIDatePicker").Invoke("setDate", DateTime.Today.AddHours(time.Hour).AddMinutes(time.Minute), "animated", true));
app.Query(c => c.Class("UIDatePicker").Invoke("accessibilityActivate"));
```

where time was `DateTime` object with desired time. This worked without adding `"animated", true` as well.

When trying to check this in REPL I noticed that `DateTime.Now` does not set picker to the right time, whereas using `DateTime.Today` works fine. I'm not sure why, maybe someone will investigate this in the future.

I had to invoke `accessibilityActivate` to save the changes when closing picker. Selected time was not saved in my test app without it. That solved my problem, so I haven't investigated that further

Comment: This is really interesting behavior though, when you                                       
IDatePicker dp4 = new UIDatePicker();
dp4.AccessibilityActivate();                                                                                           
from actual codebase, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
app.Query(q => q.Class("UIDatePicker").Invoke("updateDate", year, month, day))
```

Month starts with 0 = January.